# Unix shell script- rpadding input file

Tags: shell, scripting

I have file has lines with comma separated values like below.

```
1234,asdfgh,2345,002500
12,defr,267896,004590
```

I want the result to be as below
1st field size is 6,
2nd field size is 10
Then 12,16 resp.

```
1234  asdfgh    2345        2500.00         
12    defr      267896      4590.00
```

Please help me on how to rpad with spaces in shell script

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, '{printf "%-6s%-10s%-12s%14.2f\n", $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
```